# Java Eclipse configuration for raspberry-pi

Tags: java, ide

I have installed java and eclipse in my raspberry-pi.Installed eclipse using

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Eclipse is installed and i am able to open the IDE through VNC.But there is no run configurations set in eclipse.It is asking for new run configurations.[image]

Even in the run configuration there is no JRE option.

[image]

I also want to add external jar files.Searched the web but didn't get much for eclipse configuration on raspberry-pi

Tried this also with no success.

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-jdt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse goto **windows->preferences** enable java perspective.

Comment: You may want to give a little more detail. about how you determined this worked. Not everyone will read the above comments -you should strive to make your answers stand alone.

Answer (score 3):

`eclipse` is just a runtime, part of a framework ([Eclipse RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform)) based upon OSGi that helps build portable applications, Rich client applications that are quick to develop and easy, fast and cheap to deploy.

> In computer programming, Eclipse is an integrated development environment (IDE). It contains a base workspace and an extensible plug-in system for customizing the environment. Written mostly in Java, Eclipse can be used to develop applications. By means of various plug-ins, Eclipse may also be used to develop applications in other programming languages. [Source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)

If you want development environments you will need to install them separately. For example, for java

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-jdt
```

... or for C/C++

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
```

Then everything is installed.

Now, you have to create a ["Java Project"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrrkxo2c5pffpy9/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-07-10%2005.46.07.png)

Before being allowed to run a class as a java program because the project metadata explains how to run them. In your screenshot, [unlike mine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5omlgnd6uf7kkn/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-07-10%2005.50.19.png) I don't see the letter J in the project icons that highlight their Java nature.

And now as my project is setup, I can execute a [class](https://www.dropbox.com/s/urcn5cj3p9o5ibe/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-07-10%2005.53.32.png).

Comment: Tried this ..but eclipse-jdt is already installed.. See my edit above

Comment: I have updated my answer. Your projects seems to lack the java _nature_. Eclipse in in java so eclipse knows how to use a jre.

Comment: Thanks .. I got it working now. The Java perspective has to be enabled from the windows->preferences option. Now i am able to compile java code from eclipse..